# React: onClick replace parent component

Tags: reactjs, onclick, components, parent, setstate

1. I have a component called "**Main**".
2. This "Main" component contains a component called "**House**".
3. And this "House" component contains a component called "**ZoneButton**" witch contains a *Button*

If I Click on the *button* I want to replace "**House**" component by another component called "**Saloon**" inside the "**Main**" component.

(unmount component and mount (load) another component instead of the first one)

Do you know how can I do that ? 
Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT** Yep, sorry, here is my 3 components

Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import House from './House';
// import Salon from './Saloon';

class Main extends Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <House />
                {/* <Saloon /> */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

House.js

```
import ZoneButton from './ZoneButton';
import zoneHouseData from './zoneHouseData';

class House extends Component {

  render(){

  const zoneComponents = zoneHouseData.map(item => <ZoneButton key={item.id} zoneName={item}/>)

  return(
      {zoneComponents}
    )
  }
 }
```

ZoneButton.js

```
class ZoneButton extends Component {

  render() {

    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.unmountHouse} style={styles}>{this.props.zoneName.name}</Button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

  export default ZoneButton
```

And zonHomeData.js witch contains the data for buttons

```
const zoneHouseData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        symbol: '+',
        name: 'Salon',
        intro_text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vel efficitur felis. Praesent at magna vestibulum lectus euismod interdum. Etiam mauris nulla, lacinia porttitor lacinia',
        image: gray,
        top: '34%',
        left: '38%'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        symbol: '+',
        name: 'Cuisine',
        intro_text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vel efficitur felis. Praesent at magna vestibulum lectus euismod interdum. Etiam mauris nulla, lacinia porttitor lacinia',
        image: gray,
        top: '51%',
        left: '38%'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        symbol: '+',
        name: 'Chambre',
        intro_text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vel efficitur felis. Praesent at magna vestibulum lectus euismod interdum. Etiam mauris nulla, lacinia porttitor lacinia',
        image: gray,
        top: '17%',
        left: '46%'
    },
]

export default zoneHouseData
```

Comment: add your code for better understanding

Comment: You have to make an effort first, we won't do your homework for you, if you show us an attempt that has a specific problem we can help

Comment: As others commented, please try yourself to fix the the problem. If it doesn't work for you , let us know what you have tried (post the code you tried). Then we can help. Either it would be a code change / or a line change or the logic change. But you should try first.

Comment: Yes, sorry you're absolutely right. I just added the 3 components. I will try to add a first solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could either store a boolean in the component's state and toggle the child components, or call both of them and modifying their classes so that they are hidden or displayed (This could be useful if you need css animations)

Main.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import House from './House';
import Salon from './Saloon';
import ZoneButton from './ZoneButton';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = { zone: true }
    }

    toggleZone = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ zone: !prevState.zone }));
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <Fragment>
                { zone ? <House /> : <Saloon /> }
                <ZoneButton toggleZone={this.toggleZone} />
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

ZoneButton.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

class ZoneButton extends Component {
    render(){
        const { toggleZone } = this.props;
        return(
            <Fragment>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => {toggleZone()}} style={styles}>{this.props.zoneName.name}</Button>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default ZoneButton;
```